# Google Apps - automatically log-in Domain user

Tags: php, single-sign-on, google-oauth, saml, simplesamlphp

Basically we need a solution (PHP based or integration possible) that will enable a user to log into our Portal with their credentials (2-factor authentication) and then should be automatically/silently logged into our Google apps domain for that particular user? What are our options here? Should we be using SSO/SAML federation of some form, or automate the login process using Google OAuth2 API's etc?

Comment: Are you trying to log the user (automatically) into their Google account (i.e. login to your portal and then get signed into their gmail)? In that case SAML is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAML2, but that's a huge effort. I would recommend integrating your PHP application with a SAML2 Identity Provider only if you're already using SAML2 to log users in.

The login process with OAuth2 is much simpler. [It is documented here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=en), with examples in PHP.

Basically you need to redirect the user to an URL like this :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
 client_id=424911365001.apps.googleusercontent.com&
 response_type=code&
 scope=openid%20email&
 redirect_uri=https://yourapp/oauth2callback&
 state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://yourapp/pagewheretheusermustbesentback&
 openid.realm=yourdomain.com&
 hd=yourdomain.com
```

The `state` parameter is detailed in the documentation, it provides both a redirect URL for your app to know where to send the user when he's authenticated, and a security token that you app must check to make sure nobody is tricking the user into logging in.

You must generate The `client_id` parameter via the [Google Cloud Console](http://cloud.google.com/console). First create a project, then generate credentials of type "Web Application" for your application. Pay attention to providing the right redirect uri.

When the user accepts the authentication, he is redirected to `https://yourapp/oauth2callback`, with a `code` parameter that you use to retrieve the user's info, including the email. This is done by a POST request :

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=the_code_you_got_when_the_user_was_redirected
client_id=424911365001.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=yourclientsecret&
redirect_uri=https://yourapp/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

The response will look like this :

```
{"iss":"accounts.google.com",
 "at_hash":"HK6E_P6Dh8Y93mRNtsDB1Q",
 "email_verified":"true",
 "sub":"10769150350006150715113082367",
 "azp":"1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "email":"jsmith@example.com",
 "aud":"1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat":1353601026,
 "exp":1353604926 }
```

Now you have the user's email, store it in session and you're good to go !

Note that this method will show a consent form to the user. If you want the consent form to disappear, add your client id to the Google Apps Control Panel in Security > Advanced > Manage OAuth Client Access, with the scopes `email` and `profile`.

Comment: Excellent - many thanks @David for detailed response! However is there anyway to avoid/bypass User redirect(step-1) - if I know the user's google email-id? (ie he is part of our google domain). Also note our Portal login/credentials are different to google domain.

Comment: If you know the user's email if, why do you want to log him in ? Logging a user in means making the application aware of the user's id. If the application already know the user id what's the point ?